# How to get Linux Mint 17, print server TP-LInk TL-PS110U and thermal printer Asterix ST-EP4 work together?

Tags: linux, printing, thermal-printer

I am here to get some help from the community. Hope I will get some solution here.

So I got my Linux Mint, and configured it successfully to work with the printer Asterix ST-EP4... But, when I connect the printer through the print server, which is the TP-Link TL-PS110U, followed  the step in Tp-Link TCP/IP configuration to change the IP and still I cannot print anything. I do not know if I have configured it wrongly or it just the print server do not compatible with the printer.

I hope somebody here will help me, as I totally know nothing what to do now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your Print Server has a different subnet mask (therefore it exists on a different network), than what's needed to be on the same network as your router/pc/(any other network device you have at home).

I'll be as simple and mechanical as I can here in this example, for you to understand. Just skip it to the solution part if you don't want to spend time on it.

Let's say your router uses the 192.168.1.254 IP address for your internal network and your PC gets the 192.168.1.34 IP address. It means your Router's built in switch is using the "1" network to share data between hosts(PC/Laptop/Phone/Tablet/Network Printer). Note the third number on the hosts and the Routers IP address!

So in the case mentioned above, if your newly acquired print server (TP-Link in this case) has a factory default 192.168.0.10 IP address, than for your Router it simply doesn't exist on the SAME network! It exists on the "0" network.

The solution:

You'll have to manually configure your Print Server first, to be on the same network. These numbers could be different of course, just go with the theory.

1. Connect your Printer to the Print Server than the Print Server directly to a Computers Ethernet port.
2. Assign a Static IP address to the Computer which is on the same network your Print Server is. E.g, if the Print Server's default IP address is 192.168.1.x than assign 192.168.1.something different than the Print Server's IP address. Subnet mask should be 255.255.255.0. The Print Server's default IP address should be listed in the manual or on the device itself.
3. Open a browser and enter the Print Server's IP address. Log in, and find the network settings. Enter any currently unused IP address on your Home Network.
   Here, you can use another PC/laptop connected to the router, sign in and look at the attached devices list to find out which addresses are used.
4. Sign out of the Print Server, connect it back to the Router. It should be on the attached devices list. BUT! Don't forget to change back to the original network settings on the computer you used to configure the print server.

Hope I was clear about this.
Cheerio!